# Unable to measure table lamp AC amps using clamp meter

Tags: electrical, multimeter

I decided to get the clamp meter in the image. And it say AC Current:60A/600A/1000A

1. What does " AC Current:60A/600A/1000A" mean ? It only has one option for Amps AC.
2. I was doing some testing and I observed I can measure the AC current of my toaster oven using the clamp meter. Which was using 9 amps.
   However, when I tried to do a test on my table lamp. I got no reading. Is it because the amp usage is too low ? Does it have anything to do with question 1 ?
   OR is it because the table lamp is using two wires where as the toaster oven has three wires because of the ground. I am only measuring one wire of the whole in the clamp meter.

[product on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08CX6VHWV)

[image]

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/581648/152903

Comment: Be clear:  Are you somehow separating one wire feeding the table lamp and just putting the meter clamp around the one wire?

Comment: @HotLicks yes, I split a 3 wire extension cord  from which I clamp onto one conductor. And I feed the device into the extension cord

Comment: I'm  shopping around more. And It's not standard to support  higher resolution low amp reading. But apparently they are out there

Comment: How about a picture of your meter or model number.

Comment: Try using the "range" button for 60/600/1000 selection. Actually the dial has different positions for 60/600 and 1000, not "only one" as you say. Perhaps start with looking at your meter and it's manual a bit more closely...

Comment: @JACK updated question with my model

Comment: @Ecnerwal ok I tried range, no luck. Just tried my friend's clamp meter with 2/20/200/400 Amp range. And it worked

Comment: My Fluke clamp meter is about 5 times the price - perhaps an example of you get what you pay for.

Comment: @SolarMike are you saying your fluke is able to read ac amps of an led light bulb using clamp.. I'm not sure about that. I'm thinking, there are specialized multimeters that work or big amps. And others work for small amps. As someone else said, you need  "leakage clampmeter" for high precision mA

Answer (score 5):

The major sellers of Mastech meters are Amazon, eBay, AliExpress, Konga, Joom, Indiamart and wish.com. That is a huge red flag for cheap counterfeit crud, right off the boat.

If that fact did not reflect the price you paid, that's because crud sellers have discovered people are more likely to buy it if it's up-priced comparable to quality units.  Also Mastech is a real brand, they just don't sell test equipment.  This "brand predation" is very typical of "those guys".

I bought a modest quality Klein unit last year for around $50, so I don't see any reason to pay that much for junk.

The lamp didn't produce a reading because its current draw is negligible - perhaps 0.1 amp assuming you are using modern bulbs.

If you cut up any line cords to wrap the meter around 1 wire, you need to replace those line cords, or shorten them and replace with a UL-listed retrofit plug.

The normal way of testing cord-and-plug connected equipment without slicing up the cord is to use a [line splitter](https://amzn.to/37FzG7I) as Doxylover discussed.  Some just spread the wires for you, for a 1x reading.  Others wrap the wires 10 times around the hole, giving you a 10x reading -- helpful for things like that lamp.

[image]

10x makes sense. Most clamp ammeters range to at least 200A, and 20A is the max for anything that plugs into this type of socket.

Realistically I think you got much too large a clamp meter for residential-tier activities.  If quality were equal, a larger "max limit" means poorer resolution on small measurements.

Comment: My $80 klein clamp meter came with a line splitter.

Comment: You need a special *leakage clampmeter* if you want really high (mA) level resolution

Answer (score 4):

> What does "AC Current:60A/600A/1000A" mean?

That means the meter can measure three ranges and report them on its four-digit display:

1. 00.00A - 60.00A (0.01A resolution)
2. 000.0A - 600.0A (0.1A resolution)
3. 0000A - 1000A (1A resolution)

> It only has one option for Amps AC.

Incorrect. It clearly has two different positions on the "range" dial for measuring current: "60/600A" and "1000A". If set to the former, it will "auto-range" and figure out which is appropriate.

Your table lamp likely draws only a fraction of an amp (a 60W filament bulb at 120V is 0.5A; LED/CFL bulbs are going to be more like 0.1A). The 1000A scale cannot display fractional amps. Try the 60/600A setting.

Comment: It might auto-range. Or it might need the range button to be used.

Comment: I tried range button, but nothing. I got a 0.045 Amps  using someone else's clamp meter  that has a range of 2/20/200/400 Amp. 0.045 A seems too low. But that's what it said

Comment: OK yeah, it's one of those LED/CFL bulbs.

Comment: @nobody, well it clearly doesn't start at 0

Comment: @endermaz 0.045A at 120V is 5.4W. That corresponds to about a “40W equivalent” LED/CFL. Totally normal.

Answer (score 1):

For low currents put the wire through 2 or 3 times and then divide the reading by the number of turns.

Comment: Normally that would work, But I need to use it on my fridge. I want to measure amp usage of some of the components in there. And they do use small amps. I was hoping not to cut the wiring

Comment: I was hoping this clamp meter that is in the higher end would be able to measure  amps...

Comment: Measuring amps is what clamp meters do.  They can't measure anything else, they don't have access to voltage to arrive at V, VA, W, ohms, PF or anything like that.

Answer (score -2):

your all wrong .It's not for use on a chord with both a neutral and a live the current flows in both directions cancel your reading out. end of story You need a single wire.

Comment: Yes, the current flows in both directions.  That's what AC means.

Comment: Yes, the clamp has to surround a single wire of the pair, or field from the two wires will cancel out. However, as everyone has said, a splitter, or a split extension cord, or equivalent solves this, and the original poster has said they're using that approach. So, no, everyone is right and you didn't read carefully enough; this is a range issue, assuming the meter isn't malfunctioning. You might want to delete this answer.